# (Android) How to find IP addresses of other devices connected to my Wi-fi?

Tags: android, networking

I found a solution. But it takes a long time. Given code tries to ping every IP addresses under the subnet. For example if 100ms is given as timeout then 25.5 Second is needed to complete whole process. What's the optimal way to do it?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button button;
EditText textview;

public String   s_dns1 ;
public String   s_dns2;
public String   s_gateway;
public String   s_ipAddress;
public String   s_leaseDuration;
public String   s_netmask;
public String   s_serverAddress;
TextView info;
DhcpInfo d;
WifiManager wifii;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    textview = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ipList);

}

public void NetworkDetect(View v)
{


    wifii = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    d = wifii.getDhcpInfo();

    s_dns1 = "DNS 1: " + String.valueOf(d.dns1);
    s_dns2 = "DNS 2: " + String.valueOf(d.dns2);
    s_gateway = "Default Gateway: " + String.valueOf(d.gateway);
    s_ipAddress = "IP Address: " + String.valueOf(d.ipAddress);
    s_leaseDuration = "Lease Time: " + String.valueOf(d.leaseDuration);
    s_netmask = "Subnet Mask: " + String.valueOf(d.netmask);
    s_serverAddress = "Server IP: " + String.valueOf(d.serverAddress);

    String connections = "";
    InetAddress host;

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode. ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    try
    {
        host = InetAddress.getByName(intToIp(d.dns1));
        byte[] ip = host.getAddress();

        System.out.println("Start: ");
        for(int i = 1; i <= 254; i++)
        {
             ip[3] = (byte) i;

            InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByAddress(ip);


            if(address.isReachable(100))
            {
                System.out.println(address + " machine is turned on and can be pinged");
                connections+= address+"\n";
                textview.append(address.toString()+"\n");
            }
            else if(!address.getHostAddress().equals(address.getHostName()))
            {
                System.out.println(address + " machine is known in a DNS lookup");
            }

        }
        System.out.println("End");

    }
    catch(UnknownHostException e1)
    {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(connections);

}
public String intToIp(int addr) {
    return  ((addr & 0xFF) + "." +
            ((addr >>>= 8) & 0xFF) + "." +
            ((addr >>>= 8) & 0xFF) + "." +
            ((addr >>>= 8) & 0xFF));
}
```

}

Comment: Actually, your solution doesn't work if any other host on the same network has a firewall that drops ICMP. There is no foolproof way to detect every host on a network because network protocols don't facilitate this, and there are ways to defeat detection.

Comment: I need to know how does app like fing (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.overlook.android.fing&hl=en) do it. Any idea?

Comment: Fing is not foolproof, either. Many tools to do this use multiple methods in order to be more effective, but none are foolproof. For example, none will work on a private VLAN.

Comment: I understand what you said. I actually don't need it to be foolproof. Efficiency same as 'fing" will be enough for me. Any links or sample code will be helpful. TIA

Comment: I don't have any sample code because I don't see such a thing as necessary, and I have never had anyone give me a real reason to do this, although I have had many people try. Also, recommendation of off-site resources is explicitly off-topic here. You could look at one of the open source tools to do this and see what it does.

Comment: If you find it unnecessary you should have stopped commenting. People might have different reasons. For example I need to do it for my research purpose. No one owes you any explanation. If you don't know how to do it just keep off. Stop wasting people's time. Your comments are totally irrelevant here. Thanks

Comment: You seem pretty hostile to someone who was only trying to help. You are the one asking for help, but radiating hostility to those wishing to help is not the way to go about it. I was only trying to point you in the right direction. If this is for a business function, it is rather pointless. All you had to say is that it is for research, which is a different story. Good luck with your attitude.